# Group array with same id

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array. There are always 2 entries with the same id and I want to group them by id.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [lfsnr] => abc
            [aktion] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [artikel] => RGUA 3
            [menge] => 20,18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
            [lfsnr] => 22013552
            [aktion] => A
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
            [artikel] => RG 0/63 UA 3
            [menge] => 20,02
        )
```

How can I do that? It should be look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123
        [lfsnr] => abc
        [aktion] => A
        [artikel] => RGUA 3
        [menge] => 20,18
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry. `code`foreach ($old_array as $key => $item) {
    $arr_group[$item["id"]][$key] = $item;
 }`code` isn't working for me.

Comment: Please add new information by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67266224/edit) your question (the `Edit` link can be found at the bottom of your post), not through comments.

Comment: Anyways, in your code you just overwrite the data at the same key. There is no attempt to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract the ids, then loop trough the input arrays and add them to an output array, with id as key:

```
$input = array
(
    array
        (
            'id' => 123,
            'lfsnr' => 'abc',
            'aktion' => 'A'
        ),
    array
        (
            'id' => 123,
            'artikel' => 'RGUA 3',
            'menge' => '20,18'
        ),

    array
        (
            'id' => 456,
            'lfsnr' => '22013552',
            'aktion' => 'A'
        ),
    array
        (
            'id' => 456,
            'artikel' => 'RG 0/63 UA 3',
            'menge' => '20,02'
        )
);
$output = array();
foreach($input as $i){
    $id = $i['id'];
    foreach($i as $key => $input_identifier){
        $output[$id][$key] = $input_identifier; 
    }
}
$output = array_values($output);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I have a warning with your code on the variable $price : https://3v4l.org/fHZIo. Replace it with $the_ids and you're good : https://3v4l.org/W29vB